# Arrayindexoutofboundsexception ArrayList customListView

Tags: android

I have a question regarding my customListview in android. I am trying to add content dynamically in the list using onclick event (tv.setOnClickListener), i have my custome country class in whcih i store my data using geter and seter method. 
Problem: When i add new content dynamically and scrolldown to the end of the list i get Arrayindexoutofboundexception

plz help

```
 public class PosterList extends Activity 
   {

 MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();

TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.posterlist);

            //Click on textview to add element in contrylist

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Country country = new Country("df","df","df","m");
                countryList.add(country);      
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    });

    displayListView();

}

private void displayListView() 
{

            //Parse my JSON and store it in to different arrays

    for(int k=0;k<len;k++)
    {
        Country country = new Country(subcategory[k],caseid[k],time[k],newpost[k]);
        countryList.add(country);
    }

    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.country_info, countryList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) 
        {

                Country country = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                country.getContinent(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> 
{

    private ArrayList<Country> originalList;
    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
        ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
    this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
    this.originalList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    this.originalList.addAll(countryList);
}

private class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView code;
    TextView name;
    TextView continent;
    TextView region;
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
    if (convertView == null) 
    {

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.continent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.continent);
        holder.region = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.region);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } 
    else
     {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }

    Country country = countryList.get(position);
    holder.code.setText(country.getCode());
    holder.name.setText(country.getName());
    holder.continent.setText(country.getContinent());
    holder.region.setText(country.getRegion());

    return convertView;

  }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem. In your `getView` method, you reference `countryList`. You have two `countryList` variables: one in the `PostList` class, and one in the `MyCustomAdapter` class. The one you are referencing is the one in the `MyCustomerAdapter` class, which is **not the data backed by the adapter**. Get your `Country` object this way inside the `getView` method:

```
Country country = (Country) getItem(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is your for loop. You have to initialize it before you add information dynamically.mso init ialize it then below that inside the for loop use the class methods to add that information. Should solve your problem.